# Traverse JSON Array with PHP works on Google Chrome, but not on Safari or Firefox

Tags: php, json, firefox, safari, facebook-fql

I have a JSON Object with one array, coming from a FQL query called $PageFansCountryFql:

```
{
"data": [
{
  "value": {
    "M.25-34": 3392, 
    "M.35-44": 2601, 
    "M.45-54": 1675, 
    "M.55-64": 863, 
    "M.18-24": 625, 
    "M.65+": 552, 
    "F.25-34": 531, 
    "F.35-44": 328, 
    "F.45-54": 159, 
    "M.13-17": 119, 
    "F.18-24": 104, 
    "F.55-64": 74, 
    "F.65+": 51, 
    "F.13-17": 35, 
    "U.45-54": 8, 
    "U.35-44": 3, 
    "U.25-34": 2, 
    "U.65+": 1
  }
}
]}
```

And I managed to traverse using the following for each:

```
foreach($PageFansCountryFqlResult[0] as $theKey => $theValue){
        foreach($theValue as $theKey2 => $theValue2){
                echo("The key2: " . $theKey2 . " The value2: " . $theValue2 . "<BR>");
        }// 2 level
}// 1 level
```

And I have other FQL queries later on. All of them are on the same php file. All of the queries return the same array (or at least, an inner array of the same form) so I use the same foreach formula.

The thing is, this code works ok on Google Chrome. However, I have tested it on Safari and Firefox, and I get The **php undefined offset 0** error *only on the foreach for this query*.

That is, as I said, all the other fql queries on the same php file work, except this one. I have used a validator and it turns out it passes the W3C validation. I also made sure the facebook session is ok (or the other queries wouldn't return anything valuable).

As a reference, the same foreach works correctly on the following result from the FQL.

```
{
  "data": [
{
  "value": {
    "MX": 2865, 
    "CO": 2384, 
    "BO": 2355, 
    "AR": 1645, 
    "CL": 702, 
    "VE": 312, 
    "PE": 303, 
    "ES": 289, 
    "US": 110, 
    "BR": 18, 
    "IT": 9, 
    "EC": 9, 
    "EG": 8, 
    "CR": 7, 
    "FR": 6, 
    "PR": 6, 
    "ID": 6, 
    "GT": 5, 
    "DO": 5, 
    "PY": 4, 
    "PH": 4, 
    "UY": 4, 
    "GB": 3, 
    "CA": 3, 
    "AE": 3, 
    "TR": 3, 
    "JP": 3, 
    "HN": 3, 
    "RO": 2, 
    "MA": 2, 
    "DZ": 2, 
    "JO": 2, 
    "IN": 2, 
    "PL": 2, 
    "CN": 2, 
    "DE": 2, 
    "RU": 2, 
    "TW": 2, 
    "TN": 2, 
    "IL": 2, 
    "AU": 1, 
    "HK": 1, 
    "KZ": 1, 
    "SA": 1, 
    "PA": 1
  }
}
  ]
}
```

What am I missing? Any ideas?

Thanks!

** EDIT **

Turns out, I tested it on another computer and using Google Chrome. Same error than on Firefox and Safari (at least, some consistency). Only works ok on my laptop. But Why other array with the same structure works ok and this one doesn't?

Answer (score 0):

I finally solved it. Sometimes the resultset was actually empty. Nothing to do with json.